# How to install XML::LibXML on Windows?

Tags: perl, perl-module

How do I install `perl` module `XML::LibXML` on windows?

thanks

Comment: What Perl build and version?

Comment: I am pretty sure that Strawberry Perl comes with XML::LibXML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `ActiveState Perl` , try this command on windows command prompt:

```
ppm install XML::LibXML
```

Comment: if you are using Strawberry Perl, CPAN should work as libxml2

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed `Perl` with `strawberry`, open a `cmd`, then :

```
cpan XML::LibXML
```

Comment: I tried this getting following error:
`No 'Makefile' createdCPAN: YAML::XS loaded ok (v0.35)
  SHLOMIF/XML-LibXML-2.0014.tar.gz
  C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Could not read metadata file. Falling back to other methods to determine prerequisites
`

Comment: I am getting Same error.

Comment: @Maverick143, "NOT OK Running make test" is not the first error message you got!!!

Comment: `No 'Makefile' created` This is the first error message I got.